# manage redirection of subfolder by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cakephp

I am using below `.htaccess` for redirecting my site from `http` to `https://www`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

I have a sub folder `staging` I want whenever I access that folder it should redirect to `https://www.example.com/staging`.

I tried with the following codes add in my root htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(staging/.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(staging/.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
```

but every time my site redirect to `https://www.example.com/` if I try without `https://www` for example

```
http://example.com/staging
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/
```

Htaccess of my subfolder is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

Server is `engintron`

Answer (score 0):

Have this code in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webroot/$1 [L]
```

Have this code in from `staging/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Test it after completely clearing your browser cache.

Comment: it is redirecting but getting error `Controller class Staging could not be found.`

Comment: it has `index.php` and basically server is `engintron`

Comment: after changing the htaccess same error, before that it was working fine with direct url `https://www.example.com/staging/`

Comment: ok try my updated answer now. I am stepping away from my computer and will be able to check back in few hours.

Comment: Do you mean `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteOptions Inherit
</IfModule>` in staging htaccess

Comment: `Controller class Staging could not be found.`

Comment: Do I need to look somewhere else?

Comment: `RewriteBase` can do anything?

Comment: Yes, I know that error is because of CMS but I change the htaceess like I have mention in my question then direct url is working

Comment: But now site root .htaccess is almost identical to what you have in question. What is your Apache version? It is difficult to guess your CMS issue since I cannot duplicate it on my Apache.

Comment: actually server is `engintron ` and `apache 2.4.27`

Comment: I try with your htaccess on root and below on staging root `RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/staging [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]`

and it's working fine now.

Comment: Rather than this you can copy same root .htaccess (as shown in my answer) into `staging/.htacces`

Comment: I try that too, but face same issue. Thanks for your time :)